# jQuery Tabs - Test if loaded

Tags: jquery, dialog, tabs, jquery-tabs

I have a jQuery dialog that is displayed on postback load. The problem however is that the dialog appears before the selected tab is set behind it, so the wrong tab is shown until the dialog is closed..

Is there a way to test and wait until the tabs are finished setting up before invoking the dialog?

Comment: Please provide us with some code. It’s hard to understand what you’re talking about when just reading your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the dialog from the tabs show event

```
$('#tabs').tabs({
  show: function(){
    $('mydialog').dialog('open');
  }
});
```